# Checking TLS peer public key instead of default verify procedure

Tags: tls

My server software is using TLS with self-signed ED25519 (for small size) certificate.
My client software is accessing said server. Considering I don't care about DNS/IP names, is it secure to disable standard TLS verification and compare peer public key against pre-shared in config? In pseudo-code:

```
tls_connect/listen(verify=false)
tls_handshake()

# does it provide same guarantees as self-signed CA deployed to both peers?
assert(peer.public_key == config.peer_public_key)

application_data_exchange()
```

Context:

- goal is hidden and authenticated small binary message transport with lowest sensible network overhead; I don't have to use TLS
- most common message size 50-200 bytes
- code is open source (Eve can easily look it up)
- I control both client and server software and configuration, deploying pre-shared keys is not an issue
- but updating configuration often enough to replace ephemeral keys is not possible
- both sides use TLS1.3

Overall I considered using:

- custom implementation of length-prefixed frames with AES-GCM payload and ED25519 signature; it's very attractive on small network overhead but I could make silly mistakes in using crypto algorithms
- standard TLS library is the opposite: very trusted but considerable network overhead. Unfortunately available TLS implementation firmly sticks to concept of certificates.
- NaCl secretbox frames. Unsure about ephemeral keys and proper way to avoid sending nonces on network.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The title seems to indicate that you want to know if using a self-signed certificate is ok (i.e. check only that the certificate is exactly the expected one) - and there are several similar questions already. But in the body you  ask to compare various approaches, i.e. TLS and self-invented ones. Also, what exactly is the *"considerable network overhead"* you see in TLS, especially once the initial handshake is done.

Comment: unless you really know what you're doing (e.g. you don't need to ask questions here), you really should avoid custom crypto code, even if it's just gluing good primitives in the recommended way, because it's easy to fuck it up. TLS 1.3 has 1 RTT latency overhead to establish a new connection and a MAC (16 bytes) every 16KB record bandwidth overhead. TLS 1.2 has 2 RTT overhead to establish a new connection. The performance of TLS cipher suites is gigabytes per second on a single core. What overhead?

Comment: You don't need to do the asymmetric crypto to establish new connection after the first time, you can resume TLS connections which is fast.

Comment: 'Unfortunately available TLS implementation firmly sticks to concept of certificates.'  What is it that bothers you about using TLS with certificates?  I get the feeling that this is an X/Y problem.

Comment: Thanks for replies. For unknown reason I can't update question, get 404 on /edit. @SteffenUllrich I'm sure self-signed cert is OK. There is one question, in pseudo-code: `tls_connect("server", verify=false) ; assert(peer.public_key == config.expected)` does it authenticate peer with same guarantees as self-signed CA?
Considerable overhead is 1-2KB in each direction during handshake.
I understand the numbers may seem ridiculous for common internet usage. This application aims to work on lowest cell data plan where saving hundreds of bytes makes sense.

Comment: @Z.T. thanks, I agree and wont write custom crypto code. In this case speed absolutely doesn't matter. 1kB/s network with 200MB monthly limit would eliminate all efforts, but there is no such offering.

Comment: @temoto: Yes, ensuring that the public key of the server matches a known good value __before any application data are transferred__ provides at least the same security as a self-signed CA.

Comment: I think session resumption would also save bandwidth compared to new session. Pinned pubkey, pinned self signed cert and pinned self signed ca are equally safe, but what do you do in case you need to rotate key because private key leaked?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich would you be so kind to write it as answer?

Comment: @Z.T. in case keys leak I can deploy new configuration within days to week worst case with offended machine physically turned off. Realistically though I understand that most likely I wouldn't know about intrusion.

Comment: You have a TLS1.3 implementation that doesn't support PSK? That's surprising, because PSK in 1.3 is both in the base spec (not an extension) and used for a vital function (the functional replacement for session resumption).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I'm using Go 1.13 stdlib crypto/tls and they kinda support PSK but API still requires certificates and setting PSK-related field to same random value on client and server doesn't make any difference. There is ongoing talk if they should support PSK [in useful for my case way] in https://github.com/golang/go/issues/6379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering I don't care about DNS/IP names, is it secure to disable standard TLS verification and compare peer public key against pre-shared in config?

Ensuring that the key of the received certificate matches the expected key **before any application data are exchanged** is enough to provide the necessary authentication of the peer, i.e. all the other certificate validations regarding expiration, match of subject ... could be skipped. The way TLS works it will still ensure that only the owner of the matching private key can actually use the certificate with a specific public key.

Of course if an attacker gets access to the private key they could fake the server. Relying only on a fixed certificate also means that easy revocation and replacement of the certificate will not work, i.e. one would need to roll out a new version of the application instead with the new expected key.